# Java. regex for parsing FTP server list

Tags: java, regex, ftp, ftp-client

I am having troubles with my regex to filter FTP server list to file/directory name and size. This is the regex I'm currently using
`(?m)^.{20}\\s*(\\d+).{14}(.*)$`
  
So, using this to filter this list

```
drw-rw-rw- 1 ftp ftp                0 Mar 17 06:10 Tor Browser
-rw-rw-rw- 1 ftp ftp          1538814 Jun 26 00:23 setup.exe
-rw-rw-rw- 1 ftp ftp           142570 May 24 05:28 satellite A665-S6086.pdf
```

I will get Tor Browser, 0 and setup.exe, 1538814

which is what I actually wants but in a list of this format

```
 -r-xr-xr-x  1 0  1001     4521014 May 23  2011 FileZilla_3.5.0_win32-setup.exenull
 dr-xr-xr-x  4 0  1001  1024 Mar  2 14:07 pubnull
```

I will get something like: ay 23  2011 FileZilla_3.5.0_win32-setup.exe, 1 and 14:07 pub ,1.

 Is there a way i can make this regex works for both types?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the following:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(
    "(\\d+)        # File size           \n" +
    "\\s+          # Whitespace          \n" +
    "\\w{3}        # Month (3 letters)   \n" +
    "\\s+          # Whitespace          \n" +
    "\\d{1,2}      # Day (1 or 2 digits) \n" +
    "\\s+          # Whitespace          \n" +
    "[\\d:]{4,5}   # Time or year        \n" +
    "\\s+          # Whitespace          \n" +
    "(.*)          # Filename            \n" +
    "$             # End of line", 
    Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.COMMENTS);
```